# Compile and run c++ code on unix server using Xcode locally

Tags: c++, xcode, unix

I am a student at a university and for our classes we must compile and run our C++ code on the University's unix server (named "BUILD"). I have to use the server because it uses gcc (whereas Xcode uses clang) and there are necessary dependencies and object files that were built on that server that we need.

*All of the code we are writing is simple CLI code with no GUIs, so I want to set up Xcode in some way where it will do all of that for me when I press "run".* The bodged solution I came up with before was to make the Xcode Project compile a bash script that used scp to copy the files to the server and then ssh'd into the server to compile and run. There were many problems with that and I really don't want to use that again. Plus adding files, if I needed to, was a not simple.

My current workflow:

1. Write code in Xcode
2. Copy code over to server
3. Use Terminal to ssh into the server
4. Compile code with terminal command
5. If build successful, then run the code with terminal command.

What I want to get Xcode to do:

1. Write code in Xcode
2. Run code in Xcode application.

And that step 2 automatically does steps 2-5 of my current workflow.

I don't particularly care about getting debugging output working directly in Xcode, if I need to debug, I'll use Terminal, but if I can get that working it would be nice.

I've looked at how to set up an External Build System in Xcode and just have a project Template for my homework assignments, but I can't find any sufficient resources for how to set this up (probably because no professional works like this). Any help is appreciated! I'm sure many students would appreciate an answer to this, though.

Comment: My advice would be to set up a virtual machine on your Mac instead. Get a copy of [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) and create a VM running whatever version of Linux you have on the University servers.